# Ring2: How to iterate classes in an RGEnvironment?

Tags: metaprogramming, pharo

I'm working with Ring2 in Pharo, where I have a tonel repo with some classes. I create an RGEnvironment and can see that it has a lot of "unresolved" behaviors representing the missing superclasses (not in the tonel repo, like Object). If I ask the environment for `allClasses`, I get also the unresolved ones, how do I get just the classes defined in the repo?

Answer (score 4):

You want to filter the classes with a resolved name:

```
env := RGEnvironment new.
RGClass named: #MyClass parent: env.
env ask allClasses select: [ :each | each hasResolved: #name ]
```

Comment: this also returns the names of classes being required (i.e. Object, Metaclass), I want only the ones defined.

Comment: When the environment creates a class automatically, it sets its properties `role` and `creator` to help to determine who and why created it. So you may use it to reject them. The other option is to reject classes without defined package if it makes sense in your case.

Comment: I ended up iterating through the environment's packages. It wasn't as clean as I expected because there are three: mine, extensions and unresolved.